# Read first line of CSV file that contains text in cells

Tags: matlab, csv, text

I have a `deco.csv` file and I only want to extract `B1` to `K1` (20 columns of the first rows), i.e. `Deco_0001` to `Deco_0020`.

[image]

I first make a pre-allocation:

`names = string(20,1);`

and what I want is when calling `S(1)`, it gives `Deco_0001`; when calling `S(20)`, it gives `Deco_0020`.

I have read through [textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) but I do not know how to specify the range is first row and running from `column 2` to `column 21` of the csv file.

Also, I want save the names individually but what I have tried just save the first line in only one cell:

```
fid=fopen('deco.csv');
C=textscan(fid, '%s',1);
fclose(fid);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but this should work for you:

```
fid=fopen('deco.csv');
C=textscan(fid, '%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
S = cell(20,1);
for ii = 1:20
    S{ii} = C{ii+1};
end
```